# CSS continuous rotation without setTimeout

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I've managed to create a rotation that only rotates in one direction by using a `setTimeout`. I was wondering if I could still achieve this without using it. The main issue I have is that if I click fast enough, it will still spin the other way.

So overall, is there a way to make it spin in one direction regardless of how fast I click.

```js
function clicked()
{
  element = $("#spin");
  if ($(element).hasClass("rotate2"))
  {
    $(element).removeClass("rotate rotate2");
    setTimeout( () => $(element).addClass("rotate"), 1);
  }
  else if($(element).hasClass("rotate"))
  {
    $(element).addClass("rotate2");
  }
  else
  {
    $(element).addClass("rotate");
  }
}
```

```css
div.horizontal {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: red;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

div.horizontal.rotate {
  transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(-180deg);
  transition: transform 0.5s;
}
div.horizontal.rotate2 {
  transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(-360deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="width: 50px; height: 50px; position: relative;">
  <div id="spin" class="horizontal">
  
  </div>
</div>
<button onclick="clicked()">Rotate</button>
```

Comment: like this? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ryZZxW

Comment: @MichaelCoker that's pretty good, just wondering if it's possible to actually make it spin faster to 'catch up' to its intended spot. I'm planning on using this in conjunction with a menu where if a user clicks a button, a menu displays and hides on the second click. Just kind of a spam protection against it spinning back. But if there's no way to do that, I can accept yours as answer. Just curious, what browsers will this work on?

Comment: spin faster after a 2nd click if it's already spinning?

Comment: browser support is ie10 & up. transition, transform, and the transitionend event are what you would look at for browser support.

Comment: @MichaelCoker Yeah, so it spins faster to complete the incomplete first spin and to complete the second spin (due to the 2nd click). I hope that makes sense.

Comment: as far as I'm aware you can't modify the animation speed mid-animation using just CSS. you might be able to do it with a library like gsap/greensock.

Comment: @MichaelCoker will probably take a look at that for future reference

Comment: I haven't really used it, but it's the most popular library I know of for advanced animation techniques. I tried doing what you're looking for using `animation-play-state: paused`, redefining `animation-duration`, then `animation-play-state: running` mid-animation but it doesn't work.

Comment: @MichaelCoker Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use a single class for the transition, and remove the class on `transitionend`

```js
var $button = $('#button'),
    $spin = $('#spin');

$(document).on('click', $button, function() {
  $spin.addClass('rotate').on('transitionend',function() {
    $(this).removeClass('rotate');
  });
})
```

```css
div.horizontal {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: red;
  top: 50%;
}

div.horizontal.rotate {
  transform: rotate(-180deg);
  transition: transform .5s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="width: 50px; height: 50px; position: relative;">
  <div id="spin" class="horizontal">
  </div>
</div>
<button id="button">Rotate</button>
```